# Python; To get the index of a value in a list, which is the same value as i in separate list

Tags: python, list, indexing

distanceorder is a numerical sort of distance

```
for i in range(0, len(distance)):
    if distanceorder[i]==distance[i]:

        RA_order[i]=RA[i]
        DEC_order[i]=DEC[i]
        epoch_order[i]=epoch[i]                 

    else:
        x=distance.index("distanceorder[i]")
        RA_order[i]=RA[x]
        DEC_order[i]=DEC[x]
        epoch_order[i]=epoch[x]
```

Comes up with error ValueError: 'distanceorder[i]' is not in list
I need RA, DEC and epoch ordered with the corresponding distance.

Comment: What are the quotes for? Don't you want `distance.index(distanceorder[i])`?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong replace

```
x=distance.index("distanceorder[i]")
```

to

```
x=distance[index(distanceorder[i])]
```

if your distance is list type, the reason you getting error because if you put in quote, it will not evaluate the value of `distanceorder[i]`, instead it will look for index of `distanceorder[i]`, without quote it will first get the value of `distanceorder[i]`

Answer (score 0):

It was in the end 
x=distance.index(distanceorder[i])

However I needed to define the size of the new list RA_order rather have it an unlimited size, thus it was searching to infinity to get an answer.